# How to change the product page design with my new theme

Tags: magento

I installed a new theme in my magento store, and everything it's working fine, but the products page has remained with the older theme. I have more than 1000 products in my store, and how can I change the product page view with the new theme?

Thanks

Comment: Once try to ask GOOGLE dude...

Comment: Your questions doesnt show your effort. After installing the new theme, is it applying to all the pages(home page, listing page, cart page etc) except the product view page?

Comment: Yes, exactly the product view page is the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to style the product page template file:

```
app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[your_theme]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

Comment: I find the view.phtml, but I don't know how to style it with the new theme?

Comment: If your custom theme doensn't include the `view.phtml` file, you can copy it (from base/default) to your custom theme in the same directory: `template/catalog/product/view.phtml`.

Answer (score 0):

Time ago I accidentally set an override of Product Design.

Fixed deselecting the option.